# Type mismatch on load from second level cache

Tags: nhibernate, memcached, second-level-cache

I have a clustered web app running in asp.net + nhibernate that relies in MemcacheD as its second level cache provider. Everything ran fine for months and today some queries started to give a type mismatch error when loading entities from cache L2. Restarting the cache appeared to solve the problem, but a few minutes later the error returned. Right now the cache is disabled and everything is working.

Any clue is appreciated.

Stacktrace:

```
System.Web.HttpUnhandledException: Exception of type 'System.Web.HttpUnhandledException' was thrown. 
---> System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation. 
---> NHibernate.TypeMismatchException: Provided id of the wrong type. Expected: System.Int32, got System.Int64 
at NHibernate.Event.Default.DefaultLoadEventListener.OnLoad(LoadEvent event, LoadType loadType) 
at NHibernate.Impl.SessionImpl.FireLoad(LoadEvent event, LoadType loadType) 
at NHibernate.Impl.SessionImpl.InternalLoad(String entityName, Object id, Boolean eager, Boolean isNullable) 
at NHibernate.Type.EntityType.ResolveIdentifier(Object id, ISessionImplementor session) 
at NHibernate.Type.TypeFactory.Assemble(Object[] row, ICacheAssembler[] types, ISessionImplementor session, Object owner) 
at NHibernate.Cache.Entry.CacheEntry.Assemble(Object[] values, Object result, Object id, IEntityPersister persister, IInterceptor interceptor, ISessionImplementor session) 
at NHibernate.Event.Default.DefaultLoadEventListener.AssembleCacheEntry(CacheEntry entry, Object id, IEntityPersister persister, LoadEvent event) 
at NHibernate.Event.Default.DefaultLoadEventListener.LoadFromSecondLevelCache(LoadEvent event, IEntityPersister persister, LoadType options) 
at NHibernate.Event.Default.DefaultLoadEventListener.DoLoad(LoadEvent event, IEntityPersister persister, EntityKey keyToLoad, LoadType options) 
at NHibernate.Event.Default.DefaultLoadEventListener.Load(LoadEvent event, IEntityPersister persister, EntityKey keyToLoad, LoadType options) 
at NHibernate.Event.Default.DefaultLoadEventListener.OnLoad(LoadEvent event, LoadType loadType) 
at NHibernate.Impl.SessionImpl.FireLoad(LoadEvent event, LoadType loadType) 
at NHibernate.Impl.SessionImpl.InternalLoad(String entityName, Object id, Boolean eager, Boolean isNullable) 
at NHibernate.Type.EntityType.ResolveIdentifier(Object id, ISessionImplementor session) 
at NHibernate.Engine.TwoPhaseLoad.InitializeEntity(Object entity, Boolean readOnly, ISessionImplementor session, PreLoadEvent preLoadEvent, PostLoadEvent postLoadEvent) 
at NHibernate.Loader.Loader.InitializeEntitiesAndCollections(IList hydratedObjects, Object resultSetId, ISessionImplementor session, Boolean readOnly) 
at NHibernate.Loader.Loader.DoQuery(ISessionImplementor session, QueryParameters queryParameters, Boolean returnProxies) 
at NHibernate.Loader.Loader.DoQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(ISessionImplementor session, QueryParameters queryParameters, Boolean returnProxies) 
at NHibernate.Loader.Loader.DoList(ISessionImplementor session, QueryParameters queryParameters) 
at NHibernate.Loader.Loader.List(ISessionImplementor session, QueryParameters queryParameters, ISet`1 querySpaces, IType[] resultTypes) 
at NHibernate.Impl.SessionImpl.ListCustomQuery(ICustomQuery customQuery, QueryParameters queryParameters, IList results) 
at NHibernate.Impl.SessionImpl.List(NativeSQLQuerySpecification spec, QueryParameters queryParameters, IList results) 
at NHibernate.Impl.SessionImpl.List[T](NativeSQLQuerySpecification spec, QueryParameters queryParameters) 
at NHibernate.Impl.SqlQueryImpl.List[T]() at Punchclock.DAL.NHibernate.UserDAO.GetUserList(QueryUser pQueryUser, Nullable`1 pTop) 
at Punchclock.Biz.UserBiz.GetUserList(QueryUser queryUser, Nullable`1 pTop) at Punchclock.Biz.UserBiz.GetUserList(QueryUser queryUser, Int32 pTop) 
at Punchclock.Net.Service.UserService.GetUserList(QueryUser queryUser, Int32 pTop) 
--- End of inner exception stack trace --- 
at System.RuntimeMethodHandle._InvokeMethodFast(Object target, Object[] arguments, SignatureStruct& sig, MethodAttributes methodAttributes, RuntimeTypeHandle typeOwner) 
at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture, Boolean skipVisibilityChecks) 
at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture) 
at System.Reflection.MethodBase.Invoke(Object obj, Object[] parameters) at Punchclock.Net.Service.ServiceProxy`1.Invoke(IMessage msg) 
at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.PrivateInvoke(MessageData& msgData, Int32 type) 
at Punchclock.Core.Service.IUserService.GetUserList(QueryUser queryUser, Int32 pTop) 
at Punchclock.Net.Delegate.UserDelegate.GetUserList(QueryUser queryUser, Int32 pTop) 
at Punchclock.Client.Controller.UcUserQueryController.GetUserList(QueryUser queryUser, Int32 pTop) 
at Punchclock.Client.Web.Record.UserControls.UcUserQuery.MakeQuery(Int32 maxResults)
at Punchclock.Client.Web.UserControls.UcQueryBase.OnQueryButtonClick(Object o, QueryEventArgs e) 
at Punchclock.Client.Web.Record.UserControls.UcUserQuery.btnQuery_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) 
at System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.OnClick(EventArgs e) at System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.RaisePostBackEvent(String eventArgument) 
at System.Web.UI.Page.RaisePostBackEvent(IPostBackEventHandler sourceControl, String eventArgument) 
at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) 
--- End of inner exception stack trace --- 
at System.Web.UI.Page.HandleError(Exception e) 
at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) 
at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) 
at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest() at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest(HttpContext context) 
at ASP.forms_query_aspx.ProcessRequest(HttpContext context) 
in c:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v2.0.50727\Temporary ASP.NET Files\punchclock_rc1\c4ca2e53\49a32ae2\App_Web_hfudjjsj.2.cs:line 0 
at System.Web.HttpApplication.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() 
at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously)
```

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?  I have something similar that's driving me nuts.

Comment: Unfortunately not :/. The cache remained disabled because in the end the load wasn't really high, we were in a preparation phase for the full load... So later the number of servers was increased and we changed to AppFabric's Cache. AppFabric is working, but it wasn't all magically plug and play like Microsoft claims. The documentation also is awful. I'm not in that company anymore, but I have friends there and they say it is holding up.